# Wordpress: Header image size?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Question:

In the "Header Image" section of my Wordpress dashboard, it indicates, "Images of exactly 1280 × 416 pixels will be used as-is." But when I upload an image of that size, the image is cropped at the top and bottom (I'm using the Hemingway theme). Plus, when I do an "Inspect Element" on the header image, it indicates the image is only 1214 x 243 pixels. Yet there appears to be no cropping in the x-direction. Both of these are unexpected considering the Wordpress instructions on the header page. Can someone shed some light on this?
Thanks in advance.

edit:  fwiw my site is www.panyadee.ac.th/test/

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in your theme's functions.php file for `add_theme_support`. This function registers support for the custom header image. Regarding the width and height of the default image, you can pass some `$args` like this:

```
$default_args = array(
    'default-image'          => '',
    'random-default'         => false,
    'width'                  => 0,
    'height'                 => 0,
    'flex-height'            => false,
    'flex-width'             => false,
    'default-text-color'     => '',
    'header-text'            => true,
    'uploads'                => true,
    'wp-head-callback'       => '',
    'admin-head-callback'    => '',
    'admin-preview-callback' => '',
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $default_args );
```

Try making sure that `height` and `width` are set.

Ref: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_theme_support

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I looked in my functions.php file and found:

'// Custom header
 $args = array(
  'width'         => 1280,
  'height'        => 416,
  'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg',
  'uploads'       => true,
  'header-text'   => false
  
 );
 add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );'

It seems like my theme is already fetching (is that the right word?) the header image at 1280 x 416, which is the Wordpress default.  Or am I misinterpreting this?

edit Sorry for the mangled code. I STILL don't know how to format code in a Stack Overflow comment

Comment: I enclosed my code in single quotes, as per the mini-Markdown formatting instructions.  But the above is how it turned out.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong there?

Comment: Perhaps the single quotes in my code are throwing off the mini-Markdown.  How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) for tips on comment formatting.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that formatting page addresses my issue.  I want to include code, which requires enclosing my code in backticks.  But what happens if my code itself contains backticks?

Comment: Backticks and single quotation marks are different characters so you should be OK.

Comment: Ohhhh--BACKTICKS.  OK trying now.  Back to the original topic, here's what I meant to type earlier:  I looked in my functions.php file and found--

`// Custom header $args = array( 'width' => 1280, 'height' => 416, 'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/header.jpg', 'uploads' => true, 'header-text' => false ); add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );`

edit:  <sigh>  I enclosed that in backticks, yet it's still garbage. I'm not sure how to better format it.  Suggestions?  If not, can you make sense of the php code?  It seems to have the default WP height and width.

Comment: Could 1214 x 243 pixels be the size of the containing element? Perhaps the image is being reduced in size to fit that?

Comment: OK that could very well be the case.  An 'inspect element' on the web page is consistent with this.  How can I verify this is what's happening?  Also, if this is the case, why would the theme functions.php indicate it is fetching a header image of 1280 x 416, but then just turn around and cram it into a header element of 1214 x 243?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57279/discussion-between-cag8f-and-henrywright).

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress cuts some area to provide an option to crop the uploaded image. You need to extend the bottom area from the cropping region according to your mentioned size.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

>> You need to extend the bottom area from the cropping region according to your mentioned size.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by this.  If I upload a 1280 x 416 image, Wordpress does not offer any option to crop.